# my c# windows form application and azure

Tags: c#, azure

i have an azure database and its connected to my c# application, i used App.config to create the connection string. when i run my program it becomes very slow, but when i connect to a local sql server its very fast. How do i make my azure connection on my application fast?

My App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
  <clear />
  <add name="fudz" connectionString="Data Source=[my server];Initial Catalog=[databasename];Persist Security Info=True;User ID=[my user name];Password=[my password];Encrypt=true;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"/>
</connectionStrings>
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1"/></startup></configuration>
```

Comment: Get used to that, otherwise take a look at the different pricing tiers of the Azure Db. In high Pricing tier performance if good.

Comment: Is your C# application running on your machine? Or in Azure?

Comment: #mjwills--- my application is running on my machine..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely to be a the network latency between your machine and Azure database. You can use certain network tools like `ping`, `tracert`, etc to see the network latency. You can then look at increasing your network connection speed (usually, via your ISP).

You can also select the Azure hosting that is closest to your location in which you are running your application

Azure locations - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/?cdn=disable

Comment: Okay thank you, i will try this. i'm in South africa and its not yet here.